# Does Visual Studio 2010 perform zero-initialization?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

C++11 allows initializing a value with zero using the expression `T();` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization). Is this feature supported by Visual Studio 2010? I ran some experiments comparing `T x;` with `T x = T();` and I concluded that the latter case does initialize the value with zero, but I am not sure whether I can rely on that.

Is zero initialization mentioned anywhere in the VS2010 documentation? The VS2010 *Initializers* page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wd1177(v=vs.100).aspx) does not mention it, unlike pages for later versions, e.g., VS2013 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wd1177(v=vs.120).aspx).

Comment: That is C++03 syntax.  So yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fundamental behaviour of the language that has been in there since the start. It was not introduced in C++11 (on that cppreference page note that "since C++11" is aligned with only the third of the examples under usage *(2)*; granted it's not very clear).

If `T` were `int` and `T()` did not result in a temporary `int` of value zero (and this is *zero-initialisation* via *value-initialisation*), the compiler would have a very serious bug. I am sure that Visual Studio does not have this bug.

As for proof, the VS2010 docs do not seem to mention this behaviour in the same place the standard mentions it (i.e. under the [*explicit type conversion*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t2cwh7y(v=vs.100).aspx) expression section). It is certainly possible that their documentation has changed/evolved/become more thorough over time, though, particularly as C++ itself added more and more ways to initialise things.

Comment: Ah okay, I thought the "since C++11" line on the cppreference referred to all three initializers `T()`, `T t = {}`, `T{}`. Thank you :)